# use cp to copy and change name of a file reading from a filelist.file

Tags: bash, for-loop, ubuntu-12.04, cat, cp

I want my script to copy the files in addresses.list (which contains the absolute path of those files) in my folder3 adding to the name of files the variable k (name of the lower folders they came from).

The script makes sense to me but it does not work, it states:"cp: cannot create regular file"; any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /folder1/

for k in $( cat lowerfolders_list ); do
    for f in $( cat addresses.lst ); do 
        cp $f "/folder1/folder2/folder3/${k}_$f"
        cd /folder1/
    done
done
```

The exact error I get is this " cp: cannot create regular file `/A/B/C/D/E/folder1/folder2/folder3/name of my $k/path_to_my_file/myfile.sdf': No such file or directory "

**EDIT**

It would be ok even if I could copy those files naming them only after the $k but when I tried to do this my output is the last file in my addresses.lst multiple times with every name on my lowerfolders_list.
This is the script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /folder1/

for k in $( cat lowerfolders_list ); do
    for f in $( cat addresses.lst ); do 
        cp "$f" "/folder1/folder2/folder3/${k}"
    done
    cd -
done
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** 
**Resolved**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /folder1/

for k in $( cat lowerfolders_list ); do
    for f in $( cat addresses.lst ); do 
    myfile=$( basename "$f" )   
    cp "$f" "/folder1/folder2/folder3/${k}_${myfile}"
    done
    cd -
done
```

Thanks to all the people that contributed.

Comment: Does your user have permission to create files in that directory? Also why are you using `cd` in the loop? `cp` doesn't change directories.

Comment: I have the permission to do it, the cd in the end of script worked for me once in a similiar script so I kept it in this one but anyway shouldn't affect in a bad way the script... I suppose.

Comment: Does using `touch "/folder1/folder2/folder3/${k}_$f"` in that loop instead of `cp` work correctly?

Comment: Nope, same kind of error: touch: cannot touch

Comment: Then you need to double check your permissions. What does `ls -l /folder1/{,folder2/{,folder3/}}` say?

Comment: Are there whitespaces in the file-/dirnames?

Comment: no whitespaces in an name/directory @r_3

Comment: Are you trying to copy your files to a file whose name has slashes in it? You can't have a slash in a filename! use `sed -i 's@/@_@g' lowerfolders_list` to substitute the slashes with something that is allowed in a filename.

Comment: No I have no / in the lowerfolders_list, i only have some _ but it's allowed in file names. @r_3

Comment: If `$k` is a file name, the `[ -d "/folder1/folder2/folder3/" ] || mkdir -p "/folder1/folder2/folder3/"`, then immediately `[ -d "/folder1/folder2/folder3/" ] || printf "error: unable to create /folder1/folder2/folder3/\n"`. It sounds like the directory doesn't exist. Those tests attempt to create the folder, then if it fails, it throws an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment @DavidC.Rankin , but the path /folder1/folder2/folder3/ already exist and the $k is a list of the names of the folders (without any /) that contains the files in addresses list: the first one in $k correlates to the first one in $f and so on.

Comment: If you are wanting to write a new file `${k}_$f` in `/folder1/folder2/folder3/`, and `/folder1/folder2/folder3/` exists, then the only reason it would fail is if you do not have `write` permission in `folder3`. That includes you being either **the owner** of `folder3` or a member of **the group** for `folder3` with `folder3` having a minimum octal permission of `0770` listed as `drwxrwx---`. The e`x`ecute permission is required as it controls **descend into** directory permission. Show me `ls -al /folder1/folder2/folder3`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  myname sudo 4096
drwxr-xr-x  myname sudo 4096 
drwxr-xr-x  myname sudo 4096  
@DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Do you have to enter a password to executed a command with `sudo`? per your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: Yes I have to write a password, but I resolved the problem with the last script I posted. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Or `myfile="${f##*/}"` or `myfile="${f//*\//}"` both of which prevent spawning a separate subshell. Always good to post a bit of `address.list` which would have disclosed the issue to start with. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but keeping commands that worked for another purpose without understanding what do they do is always going to put you into trouble. In marketing it may appear to work but in computer science, doing something you don't understand breaks very fast. Just stop that practice early. Try to first understand what is the directory structure. Read `man cd` and `man cp` and `man mkdir`.

So the `cd` command is screwing your script because it changes directory and the list of files and directories you read initially become invalid paths. But maybe I have an idea what were you trying to do.

Second thing is that it's unsafe to read list of dirs and files like that. If they have spaces in the name, it will break bad. But lets leave that for the time being.

Then you're not creating the directory structure "/folder1/folder2/folder3". If that doesn't exist prior running your script, it will also break. Use `mkdir -p`.

So my best guess for what you're trying to do will be something like that:

```
for k in $( cat lowerfolders_list ); do
    cd "${k}" 
    for f in $( cat addresses.lst ); do 
        cp "$f" "/folder1/folder2/folder3/${k}_$f"
    done
    cd -
done
```

Comment: Still not working, no folder contains spaces in the name and I already have the destination folder. The error I get is this cp: cannot create regular file `/A/B/C/D/E/folder1/folder2/folder3/name of my $k/path_to_my_file/myfile.sdf': No such file or directory